# Running Pentaho in command line not support utf8

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using Pentaho Data Integration ( kettle ) version 8.0 to write some ETLS, when I run my Job from Pentaho Data Integration GUI software in my system everything is done correctly on Mysql Database in a remote host,  but when I try to run that job ( exactly with the same config and db connections)  with command line of server,  every transform will do correctly **except utf8 character not copied correctly in database and showed unreadablysigns**but it works when I use GUI pentaho data integration with exactly same config and connections.

**My command to run the job on server**

```
/opt/pentaho/data-integration/kitchen.sh  -file="/opt/pentaho/repository/ETLS/ETL_xxx.kjb"  -logfile="/opt/pentaho/repository/ETLS/log/job_logs.txt"
```

**Configs for Pentaho to support utf8**

[image]